# How do I place the \part heading in the center of the page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir

How do I center the `\part` title, so it's in the middle of the page, instead of the middle of `\textwidth` (when using uneven margins)? I'm using the `memoir` class, which correctly places `\part` on a page of its own, but it also places it in the center of the `\textwidth`, instead of the center of the page.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[outermargin=3in, innermargin=1in]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\part{Part title}

\chapter{Chapter title}

dummy text.....

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to fix the title without defining a new geometry just for that page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a new geometry seems the best approach; but you can hide it from sight.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[outermargin=3in, innermargin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\part}{\cleardoublepage\newgeometry{innermargin=1cm,outermargin=1cm}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\partpageend}{\clearpage\restoregeometry}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

dummy text.....

\part{Part title}

\chapter{Chapter title}

dummy text.....

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove `showframe` for the production version.

Comment: I thought it'd be something to do with the titlesec package, but this works. Thanks!

Comment: @johnymm That could be done as well, but unfortunately `titlesec` is not compatible with `memoir`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I tried to use it and for some reason kept getting weird results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer just using `memoir` capabilities (less any typos).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{3in}{*} % unequal margins for the example
\newlength{\mylen} % a scratch length
\calccentering{\mylen} % 
\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{\null\vfil\adjustwidth{\mylen}{-\mylen}}
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\end{adjustwidth}\vfil\newpage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum[1]
\part{Part title}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This uses the `adjustwidth` environment to center the part title wrt to the paper width and the `\calccentering` macro to calculate the appropriate `adjustwidth` lengths. See the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) *8.5 Changing the textwidth* for more information, and also *6.4 Book and part headings* for the `\beforepartskip` and `\afterpartskip` original definitions.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! I'm relatively new to the memoir package so I haven't had that much time to study the manual. I have looked at it, but the thing is huge, haha.